# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my react native projects. When I Log in with firebase and I store data to *`AsyncStorage`* it always gets an error message when first time Log in. But at the second time, this error does not show. I'm really confused about this problem.

Dashboard.js

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        user: null,
        loading: true,
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then((user_data_json) => {
        let userData = JSON.parse(user_data_json);
        this.setState({
            user: userData,
            loading:false
        });
        console.log(this.state.user)
    });
}

Logout(){
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('userData').then(() => {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
        });

    });
    console.log(this.state.user)
}

render() {
    if(this.state.loading){ 
        return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
    }
    return(
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}> Hello {this.state.user.email} </Text>
            <Button title="Log Out" onPress={this.Logout.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to access `this.state.user.email`, but your initial state sets `user` to null. If you change your initial state to be an empty object, this error will go away:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: {},
        loading: true
    }
}
```

Comment: **this.state.user** is come from firebase sir. I mean i save this.state.data to AsyncStorage

Comment: In your constructor you initialize user to `null`. You are getting the error `can't read property email of null`. If you set user to an empty object in the constructor, this error will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs from the line :-

```
<Text style={styles.title}> Hello {this.state.user.email} </Text>
```

Sometimes setState takes some time in setting the state, before setState completes its work the render is called and in this case at that time **this.state.user** is not available till that so it throws the error.
So you can do the following to avoid such errors in future where you are using the state variables in render :-

```
<Text style={styles.title}> Hello {this.state.user && this.state.user.email} </Text>
```

or you can also declare the user variable in state in constructor as :-

```
constructor(props) {
   this.state = {
       user:{ email: ''}
   }
```